# Inserting rows into multiple tables using DAOs Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc, rollback

I have Registration page in which I am inserting data into multiple tables
      1. User Details 
      2. Security Details 
      3. User Reference Details 
      4. User Access details

For each table, I am using I am using single DAO and in turn each DAO impl has corresponding insert statement.

Now, it became difficult to handle and rollback insertions. Can we handle all insert statements in Single DAO rather than using multiple DAO. What is the best practice

I don't want to use hibernate or related ..

Answer (score 0):

If handling transaction of all the inserts in one shot is your primary concern,
then you can refer to the following:

```
    Connection connection;
    try
    {
        // Instantiate connection using DriverManager
        ...
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        ...
        // Inserts go here
        ...
        connection.commit();
    }catch(Exception e){
        connection.rollback(); // rollback in case of exceptions
    }finally{
        // release databases resources
    }
```

A commit is performed only if all the inserts are successful, otherwise the transaction is rolled back.

Comment: but my insert statements are in different DAOs and every time I am creating connection

Comment: You can use 1 connection object, 1 statement object and pass the insert statements from DAOs as argument to statement.executeUpdate(<insert statemtent from DAO>). You can have multiple inserts as statement.executeUpdate(<insert statemtent from DAO1>); statement.executeUpdate(<insert statemtent from DAO2>) etc.